# How to list all the users that have access to a directory?

Tags: linux, permissions

When I do `ls -al`, I see that "users" have access to a particular directory. How do I see what users have what access to these directories?

```
$ls -al
drwxrwxrwt  7 root     root     4096 Mar  9 23:37 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 root     root     4096 Feb 22 14:28 ..
drwxrwxrwx 65 myname   users    4096 Feb 22 20:08 tools
-rwxr-xr-x  1 myname   users 3832976 Jan 27 13:39 pfiles
drwxr-xr-x  2 myname   users    4096 Jan 23 07:57 nfiles
drwxr-xr-x  4 myname   users    4096 Aug  1  2014 dfiles
```

Comment: when you set the linux permissions like your example. Others can read/execute your directory.Because your linux permissions setting  was rwx - rx -rx or 755.

Comment: to put a finer point on what [supriady said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352415/how-to-list-all-the-users-that-have-access-to-a-directory#comment624055_352415), *everyone* that can log in to the system can *see* those files/directories (assuming they can get to the parent directory).

Answer (score 3):

To get list of users in `users` group, you could use following command:

```
$ getent group users
users:x:1021:ken,ben,dan
```

Answer (score 1):

`users` is a group, so the members of that group and all of the other groups is available in `/etc/group`.

The ArchWiki has an excellent page on [file permissions and attributes](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes).

Comment: Group `users` is not in the file. `cat /etc/group | grep users` doesn't return anything. Any idea why?

Comment: Strange, "users" should be an invalid group, then, and the GID would be shown instead of the name. Which distribution are you on?

Comment: Only non-primary group memberships are listed in `group` (but `users` should still be in it).

Comment: the group entries could be in elsewhere, such as NIS or LDAP; use `getent group users` as [Tagar did](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/499689/117549)